# Set button text without resetting location to button

Tags: xcode, button

I set the location of a button earlier in code, but when I set the text with

> [otherButtonLabel setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

it resets the button location.  I just want to set the text of the button.  If I comment out this piece, the button ends up at the location I set earlier.  If I don't, the button quickly flashes to the other location before returning.  Oddly, once every 20 or 30 clicks, it stays at the new location.

> - (IBAction)otherButtonPressed {
>     [self testrandom];

```
int xmin = ([otherButtonLabel frame].size.width)/2;
int ymin = ([otherButtonLabel frame].size.height)/2;

int x = xmin + rand() % 200;
int y = ymin + rand() % 400;
otherButtonLabel.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
NSLog(@"Completed Move%i",x);
}
```

The code around the random variable "Title" is

> (void)testrandom{

```
int r = rand() % 10;
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Othr%dButtonPressed",r];

[otherButtonLabel setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: The text actually changes based on the text I set in the "title" variable, too.

Comment: Can you give some more code? Did you subclass `UIButton`? And please share some code about `title` variable.